# Install Ruby via RVM without confirmation prompt

Tags: ruby, rvm, puppet

I use Puppet to install Ruby via RVM and was working fine until very recently (last few days or so).

I think its due to rvm wanting me to "press any key to continue". Is there anyway to force "yes" this, I've tried --force but no luck. Thanks

```
[root@local ~]# rvm install --binary --verify-downloads 1 ruby-1.9.3-p362
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Installing requirements for unknown, might require sudo password.
Always update your system first!
/bin/bash
/usr/bin/curl
which: no git in (/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin)
/usr/bin/patch
Install: git
Install: build-essential openssl libreadline zlib1g libyaml libsqlite3 sqlite3 libxml2 libxslt autoconf libc6 libgdbm ncurses automake libtool bison pkg-config
press any key to continue
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```sh
$ yes | rvm install --binary --verify-downloads 1 ruby-1.9.3-p362
```

From `yes`'s man page:

> Repeatedly output a line with all specified STRING(s), or ‘y’.

Comment: Hi, I just tried the about but didn't work :( , thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

this message is from the new autolibs feature of RVM, you can find docs of it here: https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs

You can disable autolibs using:

```
rvm autolibs disable
```

and make sure to report back to RVM it did not recognize your system => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues ... make sure to include `head -n 100 /etc/*release` (run as user not root)